# Faster method of looping through pixels

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looping through every pixel of some photos and storing the RGB numbers, plus the location of the pixel.

This is my current loop which looks like it might be a very slow version of what is actually possible - I have some familiarity with pandas hence I've used a dataframe to store the data inside the loop.

What avenues should I explore to make this more efficient? Scrap the df idea and use a vanilla list instead?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from PIL import ImageColor
from PIL import Image
IMAGE_PATH = 'P:/image_files/'

def loopThroughPixels():
    im = Image.open(IMAGE_PATH + 'small_orange_white.png') 
    w,h = im.size

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'pixLocation' : [(0,0)],
        'pixRGB' : [im.getpixel((0,0))]
        })

    i = 0
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
                i = i + 1
                new_record = pd.DataFrame({
                    'pixLocation' : [(x,y)],
                    'pixRGB' : [im.getpixel((x,y))]
                    })
                df = pd.concat([df,new_record])
                del new_record

    df.reset_index(inplace = True)
    df.drop("index", axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

---

note

Nehal's answer is quick put producing the wrong answer. Let me illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from PIL import ImageColor
from PIL import Image

# create  very small image to illustrate
i = Image.new('RGB',(2,2))
i.putpixel((0,0), (1,1,1))
i.putpixel((1,0), (2,2,2))
i.putpixel((0,1), (3,3,3))
i.putpixel((1,1), (4,4,4))

# run the algorithm:
def loopThroughPixels():

    im = i
    w,h = im.size

    pixLocation = list(itertools.product(range(h), range(w)))
    pixRGB = list(im.getdata())

    df = pd.DataFrame({'pixLocation': pixLocation, 'pixRGB': pixRGB})

    return df
```

## the result:

[image]

COMPARE THE RESULT TO THE INITIAL putpixel STATEMENTS - THE ALGOITHM IS SAYING COORDINATE (0,1) IS (2,2,2) BUT IT SHOULD BE (3,3,3).

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? You can use numpy to reshape the PIL-loaded pictures into a more indexed format.

Comment: @xysmas trying to achive the same result - a df with two columns - but I'd like to get to the result faster.

Comment: @xysmas you answer was good - why delete it?

Comment: Two reasons: 
- I made a mistake in my indexing method, so it was only retrieving a subset of the image. That's why it was so fast... 
- my answer was nearly identical to the other answer, but he had a better function for indexing -- the `im.getdata()`  bit.

Comment: @xysmas after testing the suggested answer is fast but not returning the same results as the nested loop.

Comment: you skip the initial column of pixels? 
`if y > 0` ?

Comment: @xysmas actually that bit is wrong in my code - I'll amend. His answer does not map the coordinates to the RGB values from the matching coordinates. This line in his code `list(itertools.product(*[range(h), range(w)]))` is creating the wrong list of tuples

Comment: As someone who works with images daily, I am having a hard time understanding why anyone would want to store them as a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I'm just using it as a container - then moving the data into sql-server, or a csv. We will then use the data for mining purposes. Is this a problem?

Comment: @whytheq, not necessarily, because I don't know your use case. For what I do (image processing) storing images in a dataframe is just plain weird, because it is difficult to perform the operations *I* need to do. I was not complaining, just being curious what problem you were trying to solve. :)

Comment: There are faster PIL methods to loop through pixels, try to look it up (first loop and calculate using PIL only then store in a dataframe if you need to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A faster way would be:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import ImageColor
from PIL import Image
IMAGE_PATH = 'P:/image_files/'

def loopThroughPixels():
    im = Image.open(IMAGE_PATH + 'small_orange_white.png')
    w,h = im.size

    pixLocation = [(y, x) for x in range(h) for y in range(w)]
    pixRGB = list(im.getdata())

    df = pd.DataFrame({'pixLocation': pixLocation, 'pixRGB': pixRGB})

    return df

loopThroughPixels()
```

On a file of description...

```
PNG image data, 1399 x 835, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

...it took:

```
In [1]: %timeit loopThroughPixels()
1 loop, best of 3: 324 ms per loop
```

Update (comparison with options from comments):

```
In [14]: w = 1399

In [15]: h = 835

In [16]: [(y, x) for x in range(h) for y in range(w)] == list(zip(list(range(w))*h, sorted(list(range(h))*w)))
Out[16]: True

In [17]: %timeit  [(y, x) for x in range(h) for y in range(w)]
10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit  list(zip(list(range(w))*h, sorted(list(range(h))*w)))
1 loop, best of 3: 207 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice one! So creating the two lists first > then make the dataframe. In terms of making the lists are `list(itertools.product` and `lambdas` quicker than using nested loops, or just more concise ways of writing the loops i.e. syntactic sugar ?

Comment: @whytheq The major difference here is that I am not creating/deleting/concatenating dataframes again and again.

Comment: @whytheq I have updated the answer with a better version of calculating pixRGB

Comment: I've tested your method against the old method - it is significantly faster BUT does not give the same results - I suspect pixLocation is incorrect. Try creating a very small image and comparing the two results.

Comment: @whytheq Of course, I am not skipping locations with `y = 0`. I can update the answer with that if you want.

Comment: No - I think these are the wrong way around?! `[range(w), range(h)]` ....getdata gets the information row by row, but this `[range(w), range(h)]` is column by column - so the RGB tuples are being mapped against the wrong coordinates?- if we just switch w,h it is ok?.....No swapping w & h is still wrong

Comment: What the purpose of writing `*[range(w), range(h)]` vs simply `range(w), range(h)` ?

Comment: @jadsq fancy splatting? just because?

Comment: @jadsq the syntax is irrelevant because this bit is creating a list of tuples in wrong order `*[range(w), range(h)]`

Comment: This creates `pixLocation` in the correct order to map to the output of getdata(): `(x,y) for y in list(range(h)) for x in list(range(w))]`

Comment: ...or this: `list(zip(list(range(w))*h, sorted(list(range(h))*w)))`

Comment: @NehalJWani please read my comments - your algorithm is mapping the rgb tuples to the wrong coordintae tuples - I will edit my question illustrating the problem.

Comment: @NehalJWani See the edit I made to my question. Please edit your question with something that works such as `list(zip(list(range(w))*h, sorted(list(range(h))*w)))`, or a working version using itertools, and I will mark it correct

Comment: @NehalJWani so a nested loop (I assume list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for a nested loop?) actually performs better than zip ... quite a surprise. Thanks.

Comment: @whytheq Actually, you are using `sorted()` which further increases runtime complexity.

Comment: @NehalJWani A small remark : the convention is to use x for horizontal axis (or here width index) and y for the vertical axis (or here height index) ...

Comment: Switched the `w` and `h` around and fixed my issue.